# D3 TSV Column Access

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js, csv

I'm following the D3 example from here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245. I am requesting a TSV from a remote server to create the graph. I know this is working fine because the graph will automatically change its x axis for the times given. The problem is that one of the columns of the TSV is: `temperature [C]`. I changed the values in the examples to match the TSV, but it didn't work, I'm thinking that it didn't like the whitespace:

```
d3.tsv(tsvDataURL, function(error, data) {

                   data.forEach(function(d) {
                                d.time = parseDate(d.time);
                                d.temperature [C] = +d.temperature [C];
                                });

                   x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.time; }));
                   y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.temperature [C]; }))

...
```

Is there a simple way for me to access the column by index like `d[2];` to get the second column? I've tried this before, but it doesn't work as expected. Please excuse my weak JS skills, I am very new to the whole language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the "dot" notation for object keys that have spaces or special characters in them, instead use the bracket notation:

```
d["temperature [C]"] = +d["temperature [C]"];
```

To make the rest of your code easier, you could also give the variable a new name:

```
d.temp = +d["temperature [C]"];
```

Then you can use `d.temp` in the rest of your code.